# Using Boolean And to overlay layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, overlapping-features, boolean

I am working for a project related to a site selection in which I have 5 layers to overlay to have as result:

- Zone1: area suitable
- Zone2: area not suitable.

[Boolean And](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/boolean-and-function.htm) seems to be the perfect function to use, but it only allows me to combine 2 layers.

Is there any other better function or should I proceed is steps (2 layers by 2)?

I am using ArcGIS Pro with an Advanced level license..

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to create a final binary raster where the cell is 1 if all other cells from the 5 rasters are a non-zero number and 0 if at least one cell is zero in the 5 rasters then you can use the *Boolean And* in a raster calculator expression.  The trick here is to know what is the equivalent operator, these are listed in the [working with operators](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/spatial-analyst/mapalgebra/working-with-operators.htm) help page. For *Boolean And* it is **&**.

In the raster calculator tool type into the expression:

```
"r1" & "r2" & "r3" & "r4" & "r5"
```

Where r1 to r5 are your raster layer names. Below is a screen shot of the tool overlaying just 3 rasters:

[image: Tool]

Ensure your rasters all have the same extent, cell size and coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Raster calculator is the way to go. String together a series of Boolean AND expressions and if the pixel satisfies them all it will result in a "1" which for your case would be "suitable". If one of the raster data sets contain a pixel that does not satisfy one of those the resulting pixel will be "0" which for your case would be "unsuitable".